# Почему список не преобразовывается в словарь?

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

```
def inputtodict():
    a = []
    for i in input().split():
        a.append(tuple((str(i).split(":"))))
    dict(a)
    return a, type(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код у вас почти работоспособный, нужно только присвоить возвращаемое `dict(a)` значение переменной `а`. Параметр для `dict()` вполне подходящий - это список кортежей, что соответствует [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from sequences of
> key-value pairs

В то же время в вашем коде есть избыточное преобразование `str(i)`, поскольку `i` - и так строка, и есть избыточные скобки.
Если говорить о лаконичности кода и исключении промежуточного списка, то можно использовать генераторное выражение, которое сгенерирует последовательность кортежей для `dict()`:

```
def inputtodict():
    a = dict(tuple(i.split(":")) for i in input('Введите пары ключ:значение, разделяя пробелом: ').split())
    return a, type(a)


print(inputtodict())
```

```
Введите пары ключ:значение, разделяя пробелом: 123:456 789:aaa ключ:значение
({'123': '456', '789': 'aaa', 'ключ': 'значение'}, <class 'dict'>)
```

Answer (score -1):

**dict** *возвращает* словарь, а не *заменяет* содержимое параметра

Это могло бы выглядеть примерно так:

```
a = dict(a)
```

Но это все равно вызовет **ошибку**, тк для **dict** требуется **2** параметра

Если вы хотите преобразовать **list** в **dict** используйте подобную функцию:

```
def convert(lst):
   res_dict = {}
   for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
       res_dict[lst[i]] = lst[i + 1]
   return res_dict
```

Все же, для вашей задачи я рекомендую сделать такой метод, чтобы не преобразовывать **list** в **dict**:

```
def inputtodict():
    a = {}
    counter = 0
    for i in input().split():
        a[counter] = (tuple((str(i).split(":"))))
        counter = counter + 1
    return a, type(a)
```